# Is this shadow realistic (photo composite)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I've added a man to this composite and added shadow. I made the light source more distinctive above tree, a bit left. Based on this I draw green lines to figure out the shadow direction. The shadows for the lamps look quite long, it seems the sun is quite low then? I tried to make the shadow more sharp and stronger more near the subject and more blurry, wide and transparent further away it goes.

For both of the lamps I did lines, but the lines don't seem to meet in a light source - sun. Would last picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AASTF.jpg) indicate a more accurate shadow direction?

Let me know your feedback.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The scale doesn't look right, or these lampposts must be giants!

Comment: Yeah those lampposts must be like 150 feet tall. Or the man is 4 Inches tall.

Comment: A general tip on shadows - they are never grey. In this colourised image it is not an issue but in reality the shadow always has a cast from the colour objects close by so for example a green and red apple would have those tones within the shadow colour immediately underneath it - the Impressionist painters developed this and other colour techniques which is one reason it's useful to study art history if you are going to be a graphic designer / illustrator / photographer - interesting insight here on Cezanne's use of colour https://goo.gl/9G878i

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I would say is that it should be in the same direction as both lamp posts comparing them.